# How to pass a Json array value from parent viewcontroller to child viewcontroller using alamofire in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I am getting Json response in my `parentviewcontroller` and I want to pass the array value from that response to a `childviewcontroller`.

Comment: You can set a property in child view controller and pass the value to it. There is no need using alamfire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
class parentVC: UIViewController {
...
let childController = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard-Name", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Child Viewcontroller Id") as? ChildVC
childController.arrayFromParent = arrayToPass //You can pass value to a variable in child viewcontroller.

}

class ChildVC: UIViewController {
var arrayFromParent = [String]() 
...
}
```